# Where should the credentials for mysql be put?

Tags: php, mysql, git

Logging into a mysql database requires credentials.  I have these credentials in a PHP class called `class.DBOne.php`.

This is in a git repo on a server.  I use push to deploy.

I want to share the repo with some contract devs, but I don't want them to have access to the credentials.

How do I mitigate this?

Are the credentials were they are supposed to be?

Here is a snippet:

```
<?php

// creates one instance of a database
class DBOne
{
    private $DB_USER =              'foo';
    private $DB_PASS =              'foo';
    private $DB_DRIVER =            'mysql:dbname=foo;host=localhost';

    // singleton uses static variable to ensure only 1 instance at a time
    private static $database;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->checkForClearDB();
        // self::checkForClearPostgres();
        try
        {
            // instaniate a database connection
            self::$database = new PDO( $this->DB_DRIVER, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS );
        } 
        catch( PDOException $pdoError )
        {
            echo 'pdo connection failed: ' . $pdoError->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the credentials to a separate file,
and keep the content as simple as possible,
essentially just variable assignments, like this:

```
<?php    
$DB_USER =              'foo';
$DB_PASS =              'foo';
$DB_DRIVER =            'mysql:dbname=foo;host=localhost';
?>
```

And don't add this file in version control. Add a sample file instead,
that developers should customize to their local dev database.

When you use these variables in another file,
you will have to indicate that they are in the global scope using the `global` keyword, for example:

```
global $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_DRIVER;
```

Comment: Fair enough, I updated my post to make that more clear

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Loads environment variables from a file .env to getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER automagically.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the credentials in a separate file / folder outside of the web-root and leave it out of the repository.

What you could do, is add a mysql dump with the database structure and perhaps some test data so that the devs can setup their own environment.

Comment: what is a mysql dump ?

Comment: @Zen-LeeChai mysql comes with a program to export / dump the database (with or without the structure or data). From phpMyAdmin you can also easily export mysql databases to an sql text file that anybody can easily import. Note that without db credentials the devs will not know what the db looks like and they need a database to work with.

Comment: I think what I will do is setup a "fake" database on the dev server that has the structure but none of the user's private data.

Comment: @Zen-LeeChai That would also work of course, then anybody can decide for themselves if they want a local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox). Uses top notch gpg encryption to securely store credentials that can only be accessed by specific users (or build slaves).

Comment: what is gpg encryption? how does your method compare to just keeping it out of the repo?

Comment: Keeping stuff out of the repo is of course an option (abstinence always is), but the fact of the matter is you need a way to share stuff securely, and that's what blackbox lets you do. https://www.gnupg.org/. GPG is a very popular and secure way of handling and sharing credentials and identities. I believe its agent is built in on pretty much any linux distro, and it has clients for Windows and OS.

Comment: Is it an encryption method like SHA-1, SHA-2, etc. or is it an executable ... or is it both ?

Comment: You can google gpg and learn about it. As was said, it's very popular and secure.